# best practices for handling spacing

Tags: css

I know this is a general questions, but I was wondering how to best handle a page with sections?

```
 //page

      //block a

      //block b

      //block c
```

what would be best way to give spacing to page and each block?
e.g. what I do is give margin-bottom to individual blocks.

Comment: Well yes, that is what marigns and paddings are for. What is the question here?

Comment: where to place margin and paddings. in regards to the inner blocks and out wrappers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very subjective but generally you want to create space on the bottom and on the right.  If you are putting space between elements use margin, if you are putting space between the border and the content in the container use padding.

The reason to favor bottom and right is that if you put a bottom margin on block a it will always have a space below it.  If you put the margin on top of block b then if you reused block a, or swapped out block b, you would have to also add a top margin on the other items as well.

Comment: more or less what I was looking for, tghanks

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you're wanting to do. For paragraphs I almost always do something like this. This way I only generate margins when I need to so it doesn't mess with the rest of my styling.

```
p + p{
    margin: 1.5rem 0 0 0;
}
```

For divs and other content elements I often add inset padding because each div may vary slightly in color and I want them to stay right next to each other, rather than have an empty white space like what you'd have if you used a margin.

```
.content-heading,
.content-about,
.content-footer{
    box-sizing: border-box; // css3
    padding: 0.75rem 0;
}
```

But it all just depends on the style I'm wanting to achieve. I wouldn't say there is a best practice.

Comment: Fine unless you need IE<9 support

Comment: @IanClark Not having the box-sizing property won't break it, just make it sightly taller because it's no longer inset.

Comment: No, I was referring to your use of `rem`.

Comment: Ah, right. Forgot about rem being a new thing.